# Filtering data in JavaScript and JSP

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, filter

I am using `JSP` to extract some data and then using `JavaScript` to display data in form of some graphs. But now I want to filter data for `eg: Filter data according to some manager or filter data on basis of salary`.

Since I am getting the data from `JSP`, I don't want to send a `JSP` request everytime I need to filter some data. How can I do this using JavaScript and where and in which format can I store data in `JavaScript` after getting it using `JSP`?

Answer (score 0):

Store the data as JavaScript objects. There are plenty of JSON parsers/marshallers in Java. Choose the one you like the most, and do the following:

in the servlet/controller:

```
String json = transformToJSON(myGraphData);
request.setAttribute("json", json);
```

in the JSP:

```
<script>
    var graphData = ${json};
    // graphData is a JavaScript object containing the graph data
</script>
```

Comment: Thanks. Thats a very good option. Can you please elaborate your answer or give me some link ? I am new to javascript